# Transit Visa in London

Tags: schengen, transit, lhr

I will be travelling from The Netherlands to India soon and have a flight change in London. However I also need to change airports (From London City Airport to Heathrow Airport). I hold an Indian Passport. Will I need a transit Visa ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a
>   flight and will pass through immigration control before you leave the
>   UK.

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes

Comment: If the OP says he is traveling _from_ the Netherlands, it is plausible that he has a residence permit there -- in which case he's eligible to Transit Without Visa in the UK.